# How to get AWS transfer family server id dynamically

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, transfer

I'm using AWS SDK Java to create users in transfer family service.
When I create a new user on an existing transfer server, I need transfer server ID for the call to create a user.

Server ID is a generated string by AWS like s-88ced8077ce24d99s. Whenever I recreate a new server, the server ID changed. I don't want to hard code the server ID in my Java code or even in an external file. I hope I can make a call to AWS to get the server ID somehow dynamically.

My question is: Is this possible?

- like create an alias "my-sftp-server" somewhere, which the alias name won't change and always assign to the server, so I can use the alias name to figure out the server ID.
- using tag and get it from resource group API
- Other solution? environment variable, AWS Database?

  code sample like below:

> ```
> > CreateUserRequest createUserRequest = new CreateUserRequest();
> > createUserRequest.setUserName(sftpUser);
> > createUserRequest.setServerId("s-88ced8077ce24d99s"); //don't want hardcode server ID here
> > createUserRequest.setRole(getIamRoleArnSftp());
> > createUserRequest.setHomeDirectoryType(HOME_DIRECTORY_TYPE);
> > createUserRequest.setHomeDirectory(getBucketName() + "/" + sftpUser);
> > return getAwsTransferClient().createUser(createUserRequest);
> ```

Any recommendations and best practice please.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The CreateServer API will return a server ID. If you are using another process like CloudFormation you could store the server ID result in a CF Output or [SSM parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) then access that via the Java SDK.

If you have no way to store the server ID, you could use ListServers API to retrieve Transfer servers. If you have a single server then you know its the only one. Otherwise, you could use tags, but would need to perform a DescribeServer operation on each server returned from listing to see the tags.

Answer (score 0):

The below are options to get the server ID dynamically.
I figured to set a tag with static tag name for server ID and retrieve it using resource groups service API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/resource-groups.html).